# Копирование текста из блока с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Как скопировать текст в буфер из блока с id #test нажатием на ссылку с #copy и получить alert() с помощью jQuery?
p.s. Вопрос совсем глупый, но я никак не найду времени начать учить jQuery.. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://jsfiddle.net/oneboy/yqEBj/
```

как вариант... но еще есть много разных способов.

Comment: Не работает. Вставляет тот, текст, который я ток что из редактора скопировал

Comment: если опишите задачу более детально, отвечу более правильно :)

Comment: ну у вас просто текст выводится в окошке с помощью alert(), А мне бы в буфер скопировать

Comment: извините, не совсем понял задачу...

а потом после того как скопировали в буфер куда тот текст должен попасть ?

Comment: Короче нажатием на ссылку мы имитируем нажатие ctrl+C. Потом пользователь сам должен вставить текст, куда ему надо

Comment: посмотрите вот это решение http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Comment: а без flash Никак?

Comment: без flash не будет кроссбраузерным

Comment: @oneboy а как тогда на айпад и айфон?